# ubuntu 17.10 google drive takes more than 10 minutes to load

Tags: networking, gnome, nautilus, google, google-drive

I have been looking for a solution for this for a while, but I haven found one on my own.

I am using the native Google drive mounting in gnome with online accounts and nautilus, but it takes forever to mount. I have timed it several times at different times of day and it averages around 11 minutes to mount it. During this time, if nothing else is running besides nautilus and files I do not see any spike in CPU usage.

My network usage very low, with incoming topping out at ~56k but generally oscillating between 20k and 30k. I don't have dial-up Internet, I have a cable connection averaging around 40-50 MiB/s.

After the drive mounts, if I download a file i see speeds oscillating between 1MiB/s and 4MiB/s

If i download using the web interface i generally get about 40MiB/s

I dont need the drive for anything that big, and the slower download speeds while using nautilus are fine with me. The mounting time and speed it horrendous though.

I am hoping that there is some way of fixing this while using the native methods, I know that there are some other ways of doing it out there but I would prefer not using them if I dont have to. It seems like even if it is slow, that it shouldnt be dial-up slow, and that something is wrong